# Spring Pagination ?size really affects request time

Tags: java, spring, rest, pagination

I have got a simple **CRUD** application - get some entities, convert it to DTO and send via REST controller.

I want to search by the field, that is not unique, but really rarely recurring. So when I send POST with `'field':'123'` - my app return ***only 2 records.***

The question is why when I send `?sort=someFiled%2Cdesc&size=10000&page=0`the request take a really long time (~900ms), but when I send it with size=10, the request duration is ~150ms? When the result is only 2 fields, I thought that the request should take the same time for many sizes.

**Tested on my remote machine**, because locally the time was to short to compare it.

Is this a spring problem?

Comment: Are you asking why it takes more time to return more data?

Comment: I told that it returns only 2 records - ?size should not affect it in my opinion

Comment: Ah, it was a bit unclear. You should check out your database query. If the pagination uses the common (but a very poor) way of `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, it can result in very inefficient queries. Log the SQL statements and do an `EXPLAIN` to see what the database plans for those queries.